# How to translate "Doing what makes you feel fulfilled"?

Tags: перевод

How can be translated the phrase "Doing what makes you feel fulfilled"?

I'm having trouble with the "feel fulfilled" part. According to Google Translator, it would be `чувствовать себя выполнены`, but I'm not sure.

***Doing what makes you feel fulfilled*** implies

***Doing what you love:***

> Делая то, что ты любишь/ Занимаясь тем, что ты любишь/тебе нравится.

But I have the feeling that none of these translations transmits what the expression ''feel fulfilled'' does (that combined feeling of happiness and satisfaction when doing/achieving something).

Thanks!!

Comment: As you can see there's a number of options suggested but that's about all that can be done in the lack of context.

Comment: Какое занятие приносит вам удовлетворение?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use idiom `занятие по душе` (literally "business for the soul"). Examples:

> Найди себе занятие по душе. - Find something, what you will like to do
>
> Делай то, что тебе по душе. - Do what you like to do.

Answer (score 5):

"чувствовать себя выполнены" - это бред :) even if we add the apparently missing "м" at the end.  "Делать то, что приносит удовлетворение", "Делать то, что приносит чувство удовлетворения" - that's off the top of my head.

Comment: Agree. I would add that the word "do" in the English expression likely refers not to a decision or a single act, but to an occupation which brings lasting satisfaction. If so, it could be translatated "Заниматься удовлетворяющей работой".

Comment: Э-э, вот по-английски всё хорошо написано.. А., понял - you are not Russian. No, your translation does not sound Russian ;) However, "заниматься" is OK but the OP also mentioned this word... As it's been noted already - there's no context, no way to give the best translation until we know what **exactly** is meant by that phrase, in what it is to be used, etc.

Comment: As you have correctly guessed I am a native English speaker. As such I can say with a high degree of certainty that the phrase "to do what makes one feel fulfilled" refers to a pattern of worthwhile activity which conveys a sense of purpose in life. "аниматься тем, то ты любишь" probably comes close, but is not so noble. Having thought about it some more I have to say that "делать то, что приносит удовлетворение" falls short. Fulfillment is far more than a sense of satisfaction.

Comment: meant: in what *text* it is to be used... Time to sleep.

Comment: @DavidC ""делать то, что приносит удовлетворение" falls short" - yes, it does. That was something off the top of my head.  Note that in the OP's question the exact phrase is "*Doing* what makes you feel fulfilled" and also note that he himself suggests a translation using a "деепричастный оборот" - "делая, занимаясь".. This does not necessarily mean that the phrase is part of some full sentence, as I initially thought, but I'll refrain from guessing and wait for the context.  PS: and your "Заниматься удовлетворяющей работой" is not acceptable either, for a Russian ear it sounds similar to ...

Comment: @DavidC .. the way the phrase "Doing satisfying work" sounds for an English ear :)

Comment: I had thought that "Заниматься удовлетворяющей работой" was a phrase I had seen in use, but Google says I am wrong. Probably I took something like "труд, приносящий удовлетворение" and combined it with the structure of "doing satisfying work" (which sounds very well to the English ear and is actually used to discuss this subject). It is very difficult to prevent phrases from one's native language from breaking through.

Comment: >"doing satisfying work" (which sounds very well to the English ear..  Indeed, checked with google. That's another demonstration of how a non-native speaker (in this case - me) subconsciously translates a phrase into his mother tongue and makes (wrong) conclusions..

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

> Делай то, что делает твою жизнь осмысленной.

or

> Делай то, что наполняет твою жизнь смыслом.

The best translation of "to feel fulfilled" that I can think of is *чувствовать себя самореализованным*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "fulfilled" means "воплощенным" here, sooner than "выполненным", but that doesn't make things much better, I am afraid :)
I would translate "do what makes you feel fulfilled" as "занимайся тем, в чем ты видишь свое предназначение". 
And no, it is not at all the same as "doing what you like", as the accepted answer incorrectly suggests.

Comment: ну, "воплощенным" дейтвительно трудно притянуть к этому контексту, хоть у слова такой перевод несомненно есть.  Есть в русском такое понятие (кот. я лично не очень люблю, поскольку в последнее время его частенько пихают, куда ни попадя), как "{само}реализоваться"/"реализовываться" обычно с дополнением "как профессионал", "как мужчина/женщина" и т.п. Вот примерно в таком смысле здесь "fulfilled".  Да, "предназначение" тоже близко, но как-то слегка пафосно, что ли... Это уже, ни больше, ни меньше - "Destiny" будет, и непременно с большой буквы. :)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev т.е., вы предлагаете "заниматься тем, что помогает тебя чувствовать себя _самореализовавшимся_"? Вы это серьезно? :D

Comment: Самореализация, действительно не подразумевает задания целей извне, но и не отрицает. Так же, как и предназначение. (Точнее, предназначение - это цель (заданная извне или изнутри - не важно), а "самореализация" - процесс (самостоятельного) ее достижения). Разницы нет, если даже вы (думаете что) ее видите :)

Comment: Я флуд потру, спор не имеет смысла..

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильны все версии, все зависит от того, на каком уровне это говорится I believe all variants are correct, depending on the register.
На бытовом(как минимум)(not covering the full meaning )

> Делай то,что тебе по душе/нравится.

На лекции психолога 
(A psychologist speaking ):

> Делайте то, что поможет вам полностью **реализовать свои возможности** / быть **довольным самим собой/жизнью**,принесет вам **чувство удовлетворения**(bookish,official ),etc.

Strictly speaking, there's no context.